# Symbolic equation pair with two unknowns

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic

I am a beginner with Mathematica, so hopefully my problem is clearly presented.

My problem is solving two unknowns from equation pair with five symbolic parameters. Baghdadi et al. (2016) created semi empirical-radar backscattering model for bare soil surfaces. Variables here are radar sensor related (VV-backscatter, HV-backscatter and local incidence angle) and soil property related (soil roughness and volumetric moisture). I have only the radar data available, so the soil parameters remain unknown. I am interested in solving/inverting the equations so that the output would be two new equations for solving/estimating the soil roughness and moisture variables using the Radar sensor parameters

Symbols in my equations: VV-backscatter = v, HV-backscatter = h, local incidence angle = q, soil roughness = k, soil moisture =m.

```
vars = Complement[Variables[{m, k}]]

egns = { {
    {v == 10^(-1.138)*(Cos[q]^1.528 )*10^(0.008*Cot[q]*m)*
       k^ (0.71*Sin[q]), 
     h == 10^(-2.325)*(Cos[q]^(-0.01))*10^(0.011*Cot[q]*m)*
       k^(0.44* Sin[q])},
    {\[Placeholder]}
   } };
soln = Solve[egns, vars]
```

I get this message: Syntax:syntaxtsntxi - Syntax is incomplete; more input is needed. Is there some sort of syntax error in my code, or are equations actually unsolvable this way?

Reference:

Baghdadi, N.; Choker, M.; Zribi, M.; Hajj, M.E.; Paloscia, S.; Verhoest, N.E.C.; Lievens, H.; Baup, F.; Mattia, F. A New Empirical Model for Radar Scattering from Bare Soil Surfaces. Remote Sens. 2016, 8, 920. 
https://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/8/11/920

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your problem right the equations you want to solve are

```
eqn = {v ==10^(-1.138)*(Cos[q]^1.528)*10^(0.008*Cot[q]*m)*k^(0.71*Sin[q]), 
h == 10^(-2.325)*(Cos[q]^(-0.01))*10^(0.011*Cot[q]*m)*k^(0.44*Sin[q])}
```

which can be solved for `m,k`

```
Solve[eqn, {m, k}]
(*{m -> 5.01855*10^-35 (5.34162*10^36 + 1.43221*10^36 Log[h] -8.87567*10^35 Log[v] + 1.37052*10^36 Log[Cos[q]]) Tan[q], 
k -> E^(1.79234*10^-34 Csc[q] (-1.82131*10^34 - 1.04043*10^34 Log[h] +1.43059*10^34 Log[v] - 2.19634*10^34 Log[Cos[q]]))}*)
```

Comment: So it was just a simple error of using braces wrongly. Thank you for this!

Comment: You're welcome. I was wondering about the placeholder inside the equations...